# Difference between MODIS sinusoidal and integerized sinusoidal grid

Tags: coordinate-system

What are the differences between the MODIS sinusoidal and MODIS integerized sinusoidal grid? The sinusoidal grid seems to be currently used, whereas the integerized sinusoidal grid is marked obsolete (click "obsolete grids" at the very end of the page):

http://modis-land.gsfc.nasa.gov/MODLAND_grid.html

I'm also interested into why it is obsolete now, albeit it was invented later(?).

What advantages and disadvantages instoring and retreiving data do they have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The integrized grid is sparse, in a sense it is a ragged array. Looks like the sinusoidal one really is a full array, albeit with empty tiles.

The integrized sinusoidal grid is still used by the ocean colour group for L3BIN MODIS (and VIIRS, SeaWiFS, CZCS etc), recently converted from HDF4 to NetCDF4 (as compound types within groups) fwiw.
The bins are rarely used outside of expert groups, but very useful and well explained here: http://oceancolor.gsfc.nasa.gov/cms/L3Bins.html

Most users who need this complexity use the individual swaths from L2, but it's a bit of a missed opportunity imo. The L3 bins are a very efficient and precise way to use these data, but it takes a bit of programming nouse and is better suited to a database implementation (imo).